# How to integrate Jersey client into my servlet code using Maven

Tags: java, maven, servlets, neo4j, jersey-client

I am trying to use the Jersey client as in the chapter 7.1 of the 2.2.9 Neo4j manual. Here are my maven dependencies

```
       <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my code, I import like this:

```
 import org.glassfish.jersey.api.client.*;
```

but when I compile the specific Jersey classes Client, ClientResponse and WebResource are not found.

I have tried various dependencies and imports and nothing seems to work.

What's the right way as of April 2016?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so these classes `ClientResponse`, `WebResource` are from Jersey 1.x client, which differs completely from Jersey 2.x. If you want to follow along with the guide, and use 1.x, just use the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And add the following for JSON/POJO support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You will also need to configure the JSON/POJO support on the client

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

If you want to use the newer 2.x client (the dependencies you currently have), have a look at [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html). Also, if you decide to go with 2.x, you don't need `jersey-container-servlet`. That is only for server implementation, and you will be pulling in a bunch of jars that aren't needed.